# How can I achieve UITableViewCell margins like this (pic)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uitableview

I quite like the way that padding has been added to the `UITableViewCell`s in this app. I doubt it's possible in Storyboard, but what's the best way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Use the table view's `contentInsets` property. Not sure if you can set that in a storyboard though.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily do this in storyboard I think.

Just add a custom cell, grey background. 
On that add a `UIView` as a subview, with a white background, and arrange the size so that it becomes a smaller rectangle inside your cell, so it gets this margin effect.

Then add your labels/imageviews on that white subview and you're good.

Anything wrong with that approach?
Feels a bit like cheating, but why not?

Comment: This wouldn't work if you have a Disclosure Indicator (as I do) because it's part of the `UITableViewCell` rather than the `UIView`.

Comment: @Sebastian you can set imageView with your disclosure indicator image on uiview

Answer (score 0):

Using Storyboard this can be a daunting layout to achieve with `UITableView` on iOS 7. Programmatically it can be done fairly easily, with a bit of patience.

Anyway, given the quantity of information in the cell, I'd be tempted to use a `UICollectionView` with a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` instead of a table. This might make things easier for you as you can set the cells size, sections margin, minimum distance between items, etc. all within Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to make custom table cell and add specific background

```
@implementation CustomTableViewCell

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

        <init your custom cell here> 

        UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        CGRect whiteRect = CGRectInset(bgView.bounds, 10, 5);
        UIView *innerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:whiteRect];
        innerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        innerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [bgView addSubview:innerView];
        bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:225.0/255 green:224.0/255 blue:230.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        self.backgroundView = bgView;

    }

    return self;
}
```

Also here you can add self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView in the same way to assign the specific view to your cell while it is highlighted/selected.

[image]